# Where has the disk space on Linux gone?

Tags: linux

I have a [DigitalOcean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DigitalOcean) [droplet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DigitalOcean#Products_and_business_model) which is almost out of disk space:

```
df -h
```

Output:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            461M     0  461M   0% /dev
tmpfs            99M  880K   98M   1% /run
/dev/vda1        25G   22G  2.6G  90% /
tmpfs           493M     0  493M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           493M     0  493M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda15      105M  8.8M   96M   9% /boot/efi
tmpfs            99M     0   99M   0% /run/user/1000
```

But when I tried to find where the disk space had gone, I could only find 6 gigabytes (GB).

I tried `ncdu` and `agedu`

[image]

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Reboot. There may be files that have no name and will go away when the last reference to them closes.

Comment: What is your DO plan for? Is this shared or are you using droplets?

Comment: sometimes, when a file is deleted, it is not immediately removed from the disk. You can use the `lsof` command to find deleted files that are still being held open by a process. For example, to find deleted files in the root directory (/), you can run the command `sudo lsof +L1 /`

Comment: @freeman thanks for the explanation. `sudo lsof +L1` gives me a huge list of files. As server uptime is more than 2y, so probably restart will be the simplest solution

Comment: `sudo lsof +L1 | sort -k 7n,7n | tail -n 10` gives you 10 biggest deleted (but still occupying disk space) files.

Comment: How is this on-topic for Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very common cause to this phenomena, especially inside `/var` is when a file is deleted but at least one running process still own a handle on it.

In this case, this file is simply dereferenced from filesystem's table of content (the current directory) but still continues to exist.

You probably need to identify what process owns such a file and keep on feeding it. The `lsof` command may be useful.